# Django returns a tuple instead of returning data

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a simple model that is supposed to store some basic nutritional information about food, but whenever I create or edit the model it returns a tuple instead of the data.  The app is simple and these are the only models I have in them.

Here is the model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    test_field = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username


class Food(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False),
    calories = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=False),
    protein = models.IntegerField(default=0),
    fat = models.IntegerField(default=0),
    rel_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

At first I thought it was an issue with how I was saving the model, so I tried creating one through the shell with the following commands:

```
from api.models import User, Food
f = Food()
f.name = "Test"
f.calories = 1
f.rel_user = User.objects.get(id=1)
f.save()
```

If I call `f.rel_user`, it returns `myemail@gmail.com`, but if I call `f.name`, it returns `(<django.db.models.fields.CharField>,)`.

In order to try to fix this, I've looked through the getting started project on `https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/intro/tutorial01/`, and have made sure that my settings.py, and my models are written like the ones on the site.  I've tried using both the shell and a form to create test Food objects.

How can I fix this so when I try to get data from the food object it returns the actual value saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Food(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False),
    calories = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=False),
    protein = models.IntegerField(default=0),
    fat = models.IntegerField(default=0),
```

You're getting tuples because you put a comma after these fields.

Remove the commas.

`rel_user` didn't have a comma, so that field worked as expected.

Comment: This worked!  I'm coming back to this after a few years away, so I guess I'm a bit rusty or this changed.  Thank you so much for your help!